# Change Spark DataFrame to Standard R dataframe

Tags: r, apache-spark

I am using Databricks and have uploaded an external file from data lake. I have used the following code to import the data, using the library SparkR:

```
df = read.df("adl://test.azuredatalakestore.net/test.csv", source = 'csv', header = TRUE)
```

It is a Spark DataFrame, and it has restricted me from doing some manipulations on it. I can't import the file by using `read.csv` so is there a way that I could change it to a normal DataFrame so I could perform some changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data fits in memory you can do :

```
 local_df <- collect(df)
```

Comment: I had to restart everything and tried it again. It works now, Thank you

Comment: This will dump all data into driver so memory could result in crash if spark DF is big. If you want to see the data try to see its top few rows or sample. If you want to see whole data better write spark DF into hive table and see it there.

Comment: Indeed @abhiieor I wrote that answer against my own will. But I know that if I don't some other smart-a** will. Eventually the OP will find that what he's trying to do is a bad practice.

Comment: Actually I dont want to play smart-a** that's why not tagged you but instead more suggestion for OP if in case he is new into spark. Why not complete the answer with pros and cons.

Comment: I was not referring to you @abhiieor :)) I moderate this tag. The ones I’m referring to will know themselves. I’ll complete my answer later. I’m commuting.